# Name of an old tv show

Tags: cricket, media

There was an old program on ESPN/Star Sports. In this show, international cricketers used to participate in different small tasks like hitting the ball from bowling machine to the area marked on the grounds, getting points if they managed to hit it in the right area.

Another one is longest six. Another one is for the fielder where he has to catch the ball and hit the target.

A team has to accumulate points like this. Does anybody know the name of this old tv show??

Answer (score 2):

That Show is called **Titans of Cricket** and here is [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pE6agFjz1Q) link of that show.

Some more [information](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2011/oct/09/titans-of-cricket).